# Text-shadow effect on an html element

Tags: html, css

I want to make a similar (or the exact same shadow effect) like this one for my header(background colour may also be white, it doesn't really matter). Only the word 'hello' should have the effect, 'there' should be just as it is:

[image]

I tried it with:

```html
 <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <style>
                .hello {
                   letter-spacing: 6px;
                   color: white;
                   text-shadow: -2px 0 black, 0 -2px black, 2px 0 black, 0 2px black,
                   2px 2px black, -2px -2px black, -2px 2px black, 2px -2px black,
                   4px 3px blue;
                }
            </style>
            <div class="container">
                <h1><span class="hello">Hello</span> there!</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
```

But what I get is not that pleasing:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can make this work? You may also change the font, I don't mind it!

Comment: Your code runs just fine. I don't see the problem here

Comment: @mw509 Thanks for the comment! The problem is that it looks very different from what I would like it to be. That's the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this with using `text-stroke` (creating the border around the text) and using `text-shadow` to set the correct offset for the color blue as shadow color.

The `color` property should be set the same as the `background-color` property of the surrounding element to get the effect.
`-webkit-text-stroke` is greatly supported (only not in Internet Explorer), [read more about it at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-stroke).

What [the properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow) of `text-shadow` do:

```
text-shadow: [horizontal-offset] [vertical-offset] [blur] [color];
```

Play around with your needs.

```css
.hello {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0.09375rem #0d1b1e;
  -o-text-stroke: 0.09375rem #0d1b1e;
  text-stroke: 0.09375rem #0d1b1e;
  color: #f2cee6;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 0px #2dc7ff;
}

/* For demo purpose only: background-color should match surrounding color for effect */
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  background-color: #f2cee6;
}
```

```html
<h1><span class="hello">Hello</span> there!</h1>
```

Comment: That's beautiful!

Comment: @Fenton Thank you for your kind words.

Comment: Surprisingly, `-webkit-text-stroke` also works in Firefox. Note that `text-stroke` does **not** (FF 83.0).

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for this quick reply! Looks really great. Many many thanks! :)

Comment: `-o-text-stroke` is probably not needed since Opera **is** webkit since [2th of July 2013](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presto_(browser_engine)).

Comment: @dotnetCarpenter Thanks for verifying (and changing the code).

Comment: @Roy, actually it might be needed for Opera Mini on Android and Opera Mini's extreme compression mode which is rendered on an intermediate proxy server. According to Wikipedia, Opera Mini had a 5.01% market share for mobile browsers in June 2018. That is quite high. I am unable to test Opera Mini. Without actual testing I can not say if `-o-text-stroke` is needed or not for Opera Mini extreme compression users. Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_Mini

Answer (score 2):

You can also get closer with only `text-shadow` like below

```css
.hello {
  color: #f2cee6;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  text-shadow: 
    0 0 1.5px #0d1b1e,
    0 0 1.5px #0d1b1e,
    0 0 1.5px #0d1b1e,
    0 0 1.5px #0d1b1e,
    0 0 1.5px #0d1b1e,
    0 0 1.5px #0d1b1e,
    0 0 1.5px #0d1b1e,
    0 0 1.5px #0d1b1e,
    0 0 1.5px #0d1b1e,
    5px 5px 0px #2dc7ff;
}

/* For demo purpose only: background-color should match surrounding color for effect */
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  background-color: #f2cee6;
}
```

```html
<h1><span class="hello">Hello</span> there!</h1>
```

related: [Outline effect to text in Arabic using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64609677/8620333)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to be perfect to what you want as we're dealing with shadows, not SVG paths :D

However, if you use a set of five text shadows, you can achieve this...

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #F2CEE6;
    padding: 0 200px 200px;
}

.hello {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 60px;
    letter-spacing: 6px;
    color: #F2CEE6;
    text-shadow: -2px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1),2px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1),0px -2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1),0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1),4px 4px 0px rgba(45, 199, 255, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<h1><span class="hello">Hello</span> there!</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Correct answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64791619/75525

Answer (score 0):

This will do something of what you want, but a warning that the text-stroke properties although supported by many browsers, are not an official standard so things might change.

```css
                .container {
                  background-color: pink;
                  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
                  }
                .hello {
                   letter-spacing: 6px;
                   color: pink;
                   text-shadow: 2px 2px cornflowerblue;
                   -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
                   -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
                }
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <h1><span class="hello">Hello</span> there!</h1>
</div>
```