# webkit-text-stroke cutting the stroke

Tags: html, css

webkit-text-stroke is not working suitable, I would like to have the text stroke affect like that:
[image]

but it appears like that without cutting:
[image]

as you can seen when I write long Arabic Text like thet (ملاعــــــب) or (أهــــــــلاً) it is cutting the stroke like that:
[image]

this is my code with cutting:

```css
.myText {
    font-family: 'DIN Next LT Arabic';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 48px;
    line-height: 71px;
    /* identical to box height */
    
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: right;
    letter-spacing: -0.02em;
    
    color: #FFFFFF;
     -webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px;
     -webkit-text-stroke-color: #2A34BF;
    text-shadow: 2px 1.3px 0px #E34D32, 2px 2px 0px #D6F46B;
}
```

I also need a multi-layes shadow to be like that in the final result:
[image]

Comment: Please add an [example].

Comment: It's a known issue and unfortunately there's not much out there except for this work around: [Outline effect to text in Arabic using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64609677/outline-effect-to-text-in-arabic-using-css) https://www.w3.org/TR/alreq-gap/

Comment: it has not worked for me, it seems same as the previous result

Comment: @ZahraaMaher https://jsfiddle.net/astombaugh/hwpgdvj0/ What are you seeing on your end? You may need to tighten your letter spacing as well

Comment: Yes, but as I want to add also multy layer shadows that not work approblerly, see the last picture that I have included

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have resolved it and reach the final result using web the `text-shadow` to make all the texts joined and with about 1px stroke method provided by @kameron

and to create the multi-layered shadow I have used `filter` and add the numbers of `drop shadow` I needed

this is the final result same as the final result I needed in the post:

```css
.bg{
  background:#2A34C0;
  padding:20px;
}

.myText {
  font-family: 'DIN Next LT Arabic';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 90px;
  line-height: 71px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: right;
  letter-spacing: -0.02em;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow:
    0 0 1px #2A34C0,
    0 0 1px #2A34C0,
    0 0 1px #2A34C0,
    0 0 1px #2A34C0,
    0 0 1px #2A34C0,
    0 0 1px #2A34C0,
    0 0 1px #2A34C0,
    0 0 1px #2A34C0,
    0 0 1px #2A34C0,
    0 0 1px #2A34C0,
    0 0 1px #2A34C0,
    0 0 1px #2A34C0,
    0 0 1px #2A34C0;
    
    filter: 
    drop-shadow(-1px -1px 0px #2A34C0)
    drop-shadow(1px 1px 0px #2A34C0) 
 
    drop-shadow(3px 2px 0px #D6F46B)
    drop-shadow(3px -1px 0px #E34D32);
 
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">



<p class="myText">
   أهــــــــلاً    ملاعــــــب
</p>

</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).